# What does this html mean?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Just wondering what the 'event' keyword means in this instance? Is it a keyword and passing the actual event that will contain the keycode?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbSearch" runat="server" onkeyup="return dontSubmit(event);">

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function dontSubmit(event) {

        console.log('dont submit');
        console.log(event.keyCode);

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Yes :) It's not a keyword though, just a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event object is passed by the browser to event handlers when an event occurs in order so you can query different information about the event ( such as x/y position, key clicked, etc ).

Note: It can be named anything, so if you change `function(event)` to `function(lol)` and reference it with `lol` it would work the same way.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event for more info.

Answer (score 1):

in this case event is the `keyup` event

the `keycode` will map to which key was pressed

Here's a reference to see which key was pressed: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx

<kbd>backspace</kbd> = 8

<kbd>tab</kbd> = 9

<kbd>enter</kbd> = 13

<kbd>shift</kbd> = 16

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> = 17

<kbd>alt</kbd> = 18

<kbd>pause/break</kbd> = 19

<kbd>caps lock</kbd> = 20

<kbd>escape</kbd> = 27

<kbd>page up</kbd> = 33

<kbd>page down</kbd> = 34

<kbd>end</kbd> = 35

<kbd>home</kbd> = 36

<kbd>left arrow</kbd> = 37

<kbd>up arrow</kbd> = 38

<kbd>right arrow</kbd> = 39

<kbd>down arrow</kbd> = 40

<kbd>insert</kbd> = 45

<kbd>delete</kbd> = 46

<kbd>0</kbd> = 48

<kbd>1</kbd> = 49

<kbd>2</kbd> = 50

<kbd>3</kbd> = 51

<kbd>4</kbd> = 52

<kbd>5</kbd> = 53

<kbd>6</kbd> = 54

<kbd>7</kbd> = 55

<kbd>8</kbd> = 56

<kbd>9</kbd> = 57

<kbd>a</kbd> = 65

<kbd>b</kbd> = 66

<kbd>c</kbd> = 67

<kbd>d</kbd> = 68

<kbd>e</kbd> = 69

<kbd>f</kbd> = 70

<kbd>g</kbd> = 71

<kbd>h</kbd> = 72

<kbd>i</kbd> = 73

<kbd>j</kbd> = 74

<kbd>k</kbd> = 75

<kbd>l</kbd> = 76

<kbd>m</kbd> = 77

<kbd>n</kbd> = 78

<kbd>o</kbd> = 79

<kbd>p</kbd> = 80

<kbd>q</kbd> = 81

<kbd>r</kbd> = 82

<kbd>s</kbd> = 83

<kbd>t</kbd> = 84

<kbd>u</kbd> = 85

<kbd>v</kbd> = 86

<kbd>w</kbd> = 87

<kbd>x</kbd> = 88

<kbd>y</kbd> = 89

<kbd>z</kbd> = 90

<kbd>left window key</kbd> = 91

<kbd>right window key</kbd> = 92

<kbd>select key</kbd> = 93

<kbd>numpad 0</kbd> = 96

<kbd>numpad 1</kbd> = 97

<kbd>numpad 2</kbd> = 98

<kbd>numpad 3</kbd> = 99

<kbd>numpad 4</kbd> = 100

<kbd>numpad 5</kbd> = 101

<kbd>numpad 6</kbd> = 102

<kbd>numpad 7</kbd> = 103

<kbd>numpad 8</kbd> = 104

<kbd>numpad 9</kbd> = 105

<kbd>multiply</kbd> = 106

<kbd>add</kbd> = 107

<kbd>subtract</kbd> = 109

<kbd>decimal point</kbd> = 110

<kbd>divide</kbd> = 111

<kbd>f1</kbd> = 112

<kbd>f2</kbd> = 113

<kbd>f3</kbd> = 114

<kbd>f4</kbd> = 115

<kbd>f5</kbd> = 116

<kbd>f6</kbd> = 117

<kbd>f7</kbd> = 118

<kbd>f8</kbd> = 119

<kbd>f9</kbd> = 120

<kbd>f10</kbd> = 121

<kbd>f11</kbd> = 122

<kbd>f12</kbd> = 123

<kbd>num lock</kbd> = 144

<kbd>scroll lock</kbd> = 145

<kbd>semi-colon</kbd> = 186

<kbd>equal sign</kbd> = 187

<kbd>comma</kbd> = 188

<kbd>dash</kbd> = 189

<kbd>period</kbd> = 190

<kbd>forward slash</kbd> = 191

<kbd>grave accent</kbd> = 192

<kbd>open bracket</kbd> = 219

<kbd>back slash</kbd> = 220

<kbd>close braket</kbd> = 221

<kbd>single quote</kbd> = 222

<kbd>single quote</kbd>       =  222

Answer (score 0):

The (event) is the onkeyup event.